# Runtime error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cmb_Cancell_Click() '

    Unload uf_Estes
      
    
End Sub

Private Sub cmb_Enter_Click() 
                              
    Me.Hide
                              
    wsEstes.Select
    Range("F187").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    
    ActiveCell.Value = txt_Truck.Value 
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = txt_PU_Timein.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = txt_PU_Timeout.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = txt_PU_Trailerin.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = txt_PU_Trailerout.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = txt_Manifest.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = txt_DEL_Timein.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = txt_DEL_Timeout.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = txt_DEL_Trailerin.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = txt_DEL_Trailerout

    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 

    txt_Truck.Value = 0
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate() 

    wsForm.Select

End Sub
```

i have this code , i am new to vba , i get run time error and debuger points to this line- `Range("F187").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select`

---any suggestions...

Comment: [This is the proper way to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: And not to mention [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) :)

Comment: Range("F" & (range("F" & rows.count).end(xlup).row+1)).Select